# Mulesoft ESB Consuming the SOAP API

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-esb

I am new to mule esb i created a flow http to just check the connectivity with a SOAP API but i don't know where to put the username , password and API KEY

Anybody HELP

I JUST NEED TO DO THE CONNECTIVITY TO SOAP API.

Comment: You need to add your code.

Comment: Can you tell from flow level because i dont know about too much for mule

Comment: A little more effort in the description would be nice.. Have you tried to just Google the SOAP connector?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure UserName/Password(API Key) in Web service consumer-

1.Click on your "Web service Consumer"

2.Go to connector configuration.

3.Go to "Security" Tab.

4.There are several options available.To use username  and password,select checkbox "WS-Security Username Token" and enter required credentials.

Let us know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks Mahesh, i entered the username password there but where to enter the API key there is no such option available there.

Comment: Now i have a SOAP web service with ws security username password while in SOAP UI i am calling this service and adding the outgoing ws-security configuration username password add nonce and add created and applying this WS in sending the request. Response is showing but how to do from Mule CXF. 
Well i know that mule web service consumer has this option but unfortunately i don't know that bu using thew ws consumer but flow doesn't deployed it shows failed and in console shows some WSDLUtils.java error.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to create a TLS and the add the same in your WebService Consumer.

         <tls:context name="tlsContext">
          <tls:trust-store path="trustStore" password="pass" />
          </tls:context>
          <ws:consumer-config serviceAddress="http://localhost/soapcall" wsdlLocation="SOAPAPI.wsdl" service="SoapService" port="ServicePort" name="wsConfig">
          <ws:security>
             <ws:wss-encrypt tlsContext-ref="tlsContext" alias="keyalias" />
           </ws:security>
     </ws:consumer-config>

After that you can add the custom header like as follows:

 <set-property propertyName="soap.Authorization"
 value="<auth>clientid
 MWYxMDk4ZDktNzkyOC00Z</auth>"/>

Please refer to the following MuleSoft documentation for more details:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/web-service-consumer#adding-custom-headers
```

Comment: Hi can you please provide me the flow image of what you have said?